# Idris REPL: creating function

Tags: read-eval-print-loop, idris

How do I write a function in the Idris REPL ? If I type the function definition `longer: string -> string -> string` in the REPL, I get the following error message :

```
(input):1:7: error: expected: "$",
    "&&", "*", "*>", "+", "++", "-",
    "->", ".", "/", "/=", "::", "<",
    "<$>", "<*", "<*>", "<+>", "<<",
    "<=", "<==", "<|>", "=", "==",
    ">", ">=", ">>", ">>=", "\\\\",
    "`", "|", "||", "~=~",
    ambiguous use of a left-associative operator,
    ambiguous use of a non-associative operator,
    ambiguous use of a right-associative operator,
    end of input, function argument
longer: string -> string -> string<EOF>
      ^
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Idris documentation](http://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/reference/repl.html#adding-let-bindings) has example of what you need. You should use `:let` command. Like this:

```
Idris> :let longer : String -> String -> String; longer s1 s2 = if length s1 > length s2 then s1 else s2
Idris> longer "abacaba" "abracadabra"
"abracadabra" : String
```

By default Idris REPL doesn't do anything smart, it doesn't enter some smart multiline mode when you enter type of function. `:let` command is used to define any top-level bindings inside REPL.

Another moment: if you want to use string type you should use `String` (started with uppercase letter) instead of `string`.

Comment: Thanks, it works but is there a way to create a multi line function ? Like the definition on the first line and the instructions on the others.

Comment: Try `shift+enter` or `alt+enter` at the end of the line.

Comment: @Moebius No, there's no such way currently. Idris is very young language with poor ecosystem, unfortunately. Not much effort was put into it. There is an open issue for what you want: https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/issues/1747